# I updated my kernel to the latest version but nothing happened. What's wrong?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I was trying to install the latest stable kernel 3.15 following the steps written on this webpage: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-15/

I followed everything and installed the files, however after rebooting 'uname -r' still shows what it was showing before I tried to upgrade the kernel: 
3.13.0-29-generic

Why didn't the upgrade work?

Edit: I also tried using the command line to upgrade the kernel, but I'm getting the same result.

Edit: I ran Synaptic and I saw the 3.15 packages in the local or obsolete category. I removed them and installed them again and I noticed that when I update the grub the new kernel is available, but it doesn't boot from the new kernel...or even show it as an option.

Output on updating grub:

```
utkarsh@utkarsh-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for utkarsh: 
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.15.0-031500-lowlatency
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-lowlatency
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

Comment: Hmm, the post says to run `update-grub` but I would run `update-grub2`.

Comment: @dan08 update-grub2 is just a symbolic link to update-grub, but I still tried it...command not found. Now why is that?

Comment: Sounds like you have a default set, but it's not the kernel you want. Could you also include the output of `grep -w default /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv list` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot windows system running grub. It appears there was a legacy grub that was part of the upgrade process from prior versions of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 9.10 and later should use grub2 which does not refer to menu.lst. See: [Community Help /Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

The following will update grub to function entirely as grub2 ditching the menu.lst file so the files generated by `sudo update-grub` will actually be used, and thus your latest kernel updates will appear in the splash screen. The new splash screen will still resemble the old menu.lst based splash screen, but is graphical, rather than text based.

```
sudo upgrade-from-grub-legacy

sudo update-grub
```

Restart and check your operating kernel version using `uname -r`